# Как правильно использовать beginInsertRows и endInsertRows?

Tags: python, pyqt4

Здравствуйте.

Есть главное окно (на нём происходит вывод из БД), при нажатии на "добавить" открывается новое окно с формами для записей, при нажатии на "добавить" запись добавляется в БД, но как сделать, чтобы в главном окне запись c информацией обновилась без закрытия главного окна?

Объясните, как правильно использовать beginInsertRows и endInsertRows.

Answer (score 2):

Это из стандарного хелпа питона:

> `Help on built-in function beginInsertRows:`
>
> `beginInsertRows(...)
>     QAbstractItemModel.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex, int, int)`

А тут [примеры кода](http://nullege.com/codes/search/PyQt4.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.beginInsertRows).